# mysql function to select one or another variable

Tags: mysql, function

Is there a function in mysql where I can say

```
select one_or_another(a,b,c)
```

say if column a is not null then take a, if null take b, 
then if both a&b is null take c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `COALESCE` function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 2, 3);
```

MySQL COALESCE() function returns the first non-NULL value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce